# How to load a different view controller when changing the tab bar in the master view controller?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am creating an iPad as in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309879/how-to-update-a-uitableview-in-detailview-when-changes-the-tabbar-in-the-pop-ove). In this one I need to load different viewcontrollers when I change the tab in the masterside. How can I implement this? I have created the tabbar controller as follows: in the Appdelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    StudentVC *stdntVC = [[[StudentVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"StudentVC" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    TeachersVC *teachersVC = [[[TeachersVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"TeachersVC" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    ConfigurationVC *configViewController = [[[ConfigurationVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConfigurationVC" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *studentNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:stdntVC] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *teacherNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:teachersVC] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *configNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:configViewController] autorelease];

    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:studentNavigationController,teacherNavigationController,masterNavigationController, configNavigationController, nil];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

    ShowDetailsVC *showViewController = [[[ShowDetailsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowDetailsVC" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:showViewController] autorelease];


    self.splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabBarController, detailNavigationController, nil];

    self.splitViewController.delegate = showViewController;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;    

    stdntVC.detailsVC = showViewController;
    teachersVC.detailsVC = showViewController;
    masterViewController.detailsVC = showViewController;
    configViewController.detailsVC = showViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Here is the screen shot: [image]
Please share your ideas.

Comment: i have added, please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use method `– tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` of `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to know which viewController is selected. and you refresh your masterview

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: but where should i add this code? In the appdelegate file? and how can I refresh masterview?

Comment: you create your tabBar in appdelegate you can add this method to your app delegate and be sure you define your appdelegate as `UITabBarControllerDelegate` impelement this protocol to your .h file and add `tabBarController.delegate = self;` to your code.

Comment: to find out more information about protocols (delegates) take a look at http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Comment: now the delegate method is working, but how can I replace the view controllers in detail view?

Comment: i got the following code:      UIViewController* myReplacementVC = nil;
      if(viewController == VC1)
           myReplacementVC = myReplacementVC1;
      else
           myReplacementVC = myReplacementVC2; 

      NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:splitVC.viewControllers];
          [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:myReplacementVC]; //index 1 corresponds to the detail VC
          splitVC.viewControllers = arr;
          [arr release];, but I don't understand how it will work.

Comment: code simply replaces the viewController at index 1 of splitVC.viewControllers array depending on if statement with myReplacementVC1 or myReplacementVC2

Comment: but what should be actually VC1?

Comment: one of your navigationControllers (masterNavigationController, studentNavigationController,teacherNavigationController, childNavigationController)

Comment: i got it almost working but one more step to go, i used the following code - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    UIViewController* myReplacementVC = nil;
    
    if(viewController == studentNavigationController){
        NSLog(@"1");
        myReplacementVC = detailNavigationController;
    }else if(viewController == teacherNavigationController){
        NSLog(@"12");
        myReplacementVC = testNavigationController; 
    }

Comment: else if(viewController == masterNavigationController){
         NSLog(@"13");
        myReplacementVC = detailNavigationController; 
    }else if(viewController == configNavigationController){
         NSLog(@"14");
        myReplacementVC = testNavigationController; 
    }   
    
    NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.splitViewController viewControllers]];
    [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:myReplacementVC]; //index 1 corresponds to the detail VC
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = arr;
    [arr release];
}

Comment: but i am getting an error at self,splitViewController.viewControllers = arr;